# Operating system error 0x80090006(Invalid Signature) by Scheduled Backup TFS 2015

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, tfs-2015

I have a Windows Server 2012 R2 with TFS 2015 Update 2 installed.  I configured Scheduled backups in TFS Administration Console.

When I manually take a full backup, everything works and the backupfiles are nicely dropped on a networkshare.
However, the automatic backup (at night) fails.

From the event viewer: Exception Message: Cannot open backup device '\\...\Tfs_Configuration_9859327876866326120F.bak'. Operating system error 0x80090006(Invalid Signature.).
BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally. (type SqlException)

Help is much appreciated!

Comment: The network share is available at the automatic backup moment?

Comment: If you change a backup path, would you reproduce this issue? Check this KB to see whether it is helpful: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2686098

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mapping the network drive solved the problem!